# Error while trying to update a table column in BLOB datatype

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table 'ANS_CODEDIT_1' with a column KNK_RESP which is of datatype BLOB.

```
When I tried to update the column, I get this error

ORA-06550: line 2, column 15:
PLS-00172: string literal too long
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

Below is the code I tried to update(i have cut short the BLOB content as its too long). I actually tried with only few letters instead of the huge text. Please help as to how to fix this issue.

set serveroutput on;
declare
v_cl blob:='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:tenantProviderScreeningDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.pcsapp.cnsi.com/"><providerResponseDetails><addressVerified>Yes</addressVerified><companyNameVerified>No</companyNameVerified><feinVerified>Yes</feinVerified><nameVerified>No</nameVerified><ssnVerified>Yes</ssnVerified><upinVerified>No</upinVerified><npiErrorCode>00</npiErrorCode><npiValid>Yes</npiValid><leastSanctionRecord><address>    </address><boardType>FEDERAL BOARDS</boardType><fraudAbuseFlag></fraudAbuseFlag><lostOfLicenseIndicator></lostOfLicenseIndicator><name> </name><sanctionDate>03/03/2015</sanctionDate><sanctionId>1349</sanctionId><sanctionReason>MET ALL REQUIREMENTS FOR REINSTATEMENT</sanctionReason><sanctionState>MI</sanctionState><sanctionTerm></sanctionTerm><sanctionType>OTHER</sanctionType><source>SAM</source><sourceType>Federal</sourceType><isIncorrectSanction>No</isIncorrectSanction><sanctionName></sanctionName><screeningSource>LN</screeningSource></leastSanctionRecord><id>2728146</id><uniqueId>22302</uniqueId><hasSanctions>Yes</hasSanctions><hasLEIESanctions></hasLEIESanctions><hasEPLSSanctions></hasEPLSSanctions><hasDisciplinarySanctions></hasDisciplinarySanctions><entityType>OR</entityType><enrollmentType>4</enrollmentType></providerResponseDetails><licenses><licenseCertificationType>CLIA</licenseCertificationType><licenseNumber>SUN123C</licenseNumber><licenseState></licenseState><sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber><licenseVerified>Yes</licenseVerified><licenseValid>Yes</licenseValid><expiryDate>12/12/2030</expiryDate><nameMatchIndicator>Yes</nameMatchIndicator><licenseAdditionalInformation><licenseCertificationType>CLIA</licenseCertificationType><licenseNumber>SUN123C</licenseNumber><sequenceNumber></sequenceNumber><expiryDate>12/12/2030</expiryDate><streetAddress2></streetAddress2><dateLastSeen>12/12/2030</dateLastSeen><fullName></fullName><firstName></firstName><lastName></lastName><middle></middle><suffix></suffix><licenseStatusCode></licenseStatusCode><licenseStatusDescription></licenseStatusDescription><lastChangeDate></lastChangeDate><certificateName></certificateName><boardCertified></boardCertified><dateFirstReported></dateFirstReported><dateLastReported></dateLastReported><issueDate></issueDate><durationType></durationType><durationDescription></durationDescription><ncpdpId></ncpdpId><storeName></storeName><DBAName></DBAName><openDate></openDate><closedDate></closedDate><faxNumber></faxNumber><email></email><contactName></contactName><open24Hours></open24Hours><hours></hours><acceptsE_Prescriptions></acceptsE_Prescriptions><postalCode></postalCode><deliveryService></deliveryService><compoundingService></compoundingService><language1></language1><durableMedicalEquipment></durableMedicalEquipment><language2></language2><handicapAccess></handicapAccess><language3></language3><county></county><licenseType></licenseType><contactTitle></contactTitle><errorDesc></errorDesc><disciplineinformation></disciplineinformation><dob></dob></licenseAdditionalInformation><screeningSource>LN</screeningSource></licenses><licenses><licenseCertificationType>State License</licenseCertificationType><licenseNumber>SUN124C</licenseNumber><licenseState>MI</licenseState><sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber><licenseVerified>Yes</licenseVerified><licenseValid>Yes</licenseValid><expiryDate>06/01/2017</expiryDate><stateLicenseType>R</stateLicenseType><stateLicenseStatus>001</stateLicenseStatus><nameMatchIndicator>Yes</nameMatchIndicator><licenseAdditionalInformation><licenseCertificationType>State License</licenseCertificationType><licenseNumber>SUN124C</licenseNumber><sequenceNumber></sequenceNumber><expiryDate>06/01/2017</expiryDate><companyName></companyName><certificationType></certificationType><laboratoryType></laboratoryType><streetNumber></streetNumber><streetName></streetName><streetSuffix></streetSuffix><streetAddress1></streetAddress1><streetAddress2></streetAddress2><city></city><state></state><zip></zip><unitDesignation></unitDesignation><unitNumber></unitNumber><recordType></recordType><dateFirstSeen></dateFirstSeen><dateLastSeen></dateLastSeen><phone></phone><firstName>GuestInd</firstName><lastName>Trett</lastName><licenseStatusCode>001</licenseStatusCode><certificateName></certificateName><boardCertified></boardCertified><dateFirstReported></dateFirstReported><dateLastReported></dateLastReported><issueDate></issueDate><durationType></durationType><durationDescription></durationDescription><ncpdpId></ncpdpId><storeName></storeName><DBAName></DBAName><openDate></openDate><closedDate></closedDate><faxNumber></faxNumber><email></email><contactName></contactName><open24Hours></open24Hours><zip4></zip4><hours></hours><acceptsE_Prescriptions></acceptsE_Prescriptions><postalCode></postalCode><deliveryService></deliveryService><stateCityZip></stateCityZip><compoundingService></compoundingService><language1></language1><durableMedicalEquipment></durableMedicalEquipment><language2></language2><handicapAccess></handicapAccess><language3></language3><county></county><licenseType>R</licenseType><contactTitle></contactTitle><errorDesc></errorDesc><disciplineinformation></disciplineinformation><dob></dob></licenseAdditionalInformation><screeningSource>LN</screeningSource></licenses><taxonomies><sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber><taxonomyCode>163WC3500X</taxonomyCode><taxonomyVerified>Yes</taxonomyVerified></taxonomies><taxonomies><sequenceNumber>2</sequenceNumber><taxonomyCode>163WD0400X</taxonomyCode><taxonomyVerified>No</taxonomyVerified></taxonomies><taxonomies><sequenceNumber>3</sequenceNumber><taxonomyCode>163WD1100X</taxonomyCode><taxonomyVerified>No</taxonomyVerified></taxonomies><taxonomies><sequenceNumber>4</sequenceNumber><taxonomyCode>163WG0000X</taxonomyCode><taxonomyVerified>No</taxonomyVerified></taxonomies><taxonomies><sequenceNumber>5</sequenceNumber><taxonomyCode>163WG0600X</taxonomyCode><taxonomyVerified>No</taxonomyVerified></taxonomies><sanctions><address>    </address><boardType>FEDERAL BOARDS</boardType><fraudAbuseFlag></fraudAbuseFlag><lostOfLicenseIndicator></lostOfLicenseIndicator><name> </name><sanctionDate>03/03/2015</sanctionDate><sanctionId>1349</sanctionId><sanctionReason>MET ALL REQUIREMENTS FOR REINSTATEMENT</sanctionReason><sanctionState>MI</sanctionState><sanctionTerm></sanctionTerm><sanctionType>OTHER</sanctionType><source>SAM</source><sourceType>Federal</sourceType><isIncorrectSanction>No</isIncorrectSanction><sanctionName></sanctionName><screeningSource>LN</screeningSource></sanctions><vitalRecord><deceasedFlag>Yes</deceasedFlag><isFederalDeceased>Yes</isFederalDeceased><isStateDeceased>No</isStateDeceased><federalDOD>03/03/2015</federalDOD></vitalRecord><ownershipResponseDetails><referenceID>22302</referenceID><hasSanctions>No</hasSanctions><hasLEIESanctions>No</hasLEIESanctions><hasEPLSSanctions>No</hasEPLSSanctions><isdeceasedFlag>Yes</isdeceasedFlag><leastSanctionRecord><boardType></boardType><conditions></conditions><dob></dob><dateFirstReported></dateFirstReported><dateFirstSeen></dateFirstSeen><dateLastReported></dateLastReported><dateLastSeen></dateLastSeen><fines></fines><fraudAbuseFlag></fraudAbuseFlag><licenseNumber></licenseNumber><licenseReinstatedDate></licenseReinstatedDate><lostOfLicenseIndicator></lostOfLicenseIndicator><nppesVerified></nppesVerified><nationalProviderId></nationalProviderId><processDate></processDate><providerType></providerType><sanctionDate></sanctionDate><sanctionId></sanctionId><sanctionReason></sanctionReason><sanctionState></sanctionState><sanctionSubGroupType></sanctionSubGroupType><sanctionTerm></sanctionTerm><sanctionType></sanctionType><source></source><taxId></taxId><upin></upin><uniqueId></uniqueId><sourceType></sourceType><isIncorrectSanction></isIncorrectSanction><sanctionName></sanctionName><screeningSource></screeningSource></leastSanctionRecord><ssnVerified>Yes</ssnVerified><ssn>999266193</ssn><name>GuestInd Trett </name><isPossibleRelative></isPossibleRelative><hasCriminalHistory>Yes</hasCriminalHistory><individualBpsReports><offenseType>Criminal Offense</offenseType><ssn>999266193</ssn><firstName>GuestInd</firstName><lastName>Trett</lastName><middleName></middleName><fullName>GuestInd Trett </fullName><state>NV</state><source>Department of Corrections</source><convictiondate></convictiondate><caseType></caseType><criminalRecords><ssn>999266193</ssn><firstName>GuestInd</firstName><lastName>Trett</lastName><fullName>GuestInd Trett </fullName><sex>M</sex><stateOfOrigin>Michigan</stateOfOrigin><caseNumber>06002564-FC-A</caseNumber><caseFilingDate>08/17/2010</caseFilingDate><dataSource>Department of Corrections</dataSource><status>CLIENT DISCHARGED</status><offenderId>1234</offenderId><docNumber>609505</docNumber><caseTypeDescription>criminalreprot</caseTypeDescription><criminalOffenses><caseNumber>06002564-FC-A</caseNumber><caseType>Department Of Correction</caseType><caseTypeDescription>CRIMINAL SEXUAL CONDUCT, 3RD DEGREE</caseTypeDescription><count>45</count><county>MI</county><description>Desc</description><maximumTerm>5Years</maximumTerm><minimumTerm>2Years</minimumTerm><numberCounts>5</numberCounts><offenseDate>08/17/2010</offenseDate><offenseType>OT</offenseType><sentence>Sent Start Date: 20090522</sentence><sentenceLengthDescription>Len Des</sentenceLengthDescription><sentenceDate>07/09/2014</sentenceDate><incarcerationDate>07/09/2014</incarcerationDate><appealDisposition>Crim Appeal</appealDisposition><appealFinalDisposition>Appeal</appealFinalDisposition><arrestCaseNumber>06002564-FC-A</arrestCaseNumber><arrestDate>07/09/2014</arrestDate><arrestDisposition>Department</arrestDisposition><arrestDispositionDate>07/09/2014</arrestDispositionDate><arrestLevel>2</arrestLevel><arrestOffense>Off</arrestOffense><arrestStatute>Arrest</arrestStatute><arrestType>T</arrestType><courtCosts>Cos</courtCosts><courtDescription>CRIMINAL SEXUAL CONDUCT</courtDescription><courtDisposition>Dispo</courtDisposition><courtDispositionDate>07/09/2014</courtDispositionDate><courtFine>Fine</courtFine><courtLevel>2</courtLevel><courtOffense>Off</courtOffense><courtPlea>Plea</courtPlea><courtStatute>Stat</courtStatute><courtSuspendedFine>Sus</courtSuspendedFine><courtSentenceProbation>Y</courtSentenceProbation><courtSentenceSuspended>N</courtSentenceSuspended></criminalOffenses><criminalParoleRecords><startDate>07/09/2014</startDate><currentStatus>DISCHARGE FROM PAROLE 20130607; PAR AMENDED DATE:</currentStatus><name>Dert jill</name><paroleRegion>Houston999266193</paroleRegion><supervisingOffice>MI</supervisingOffice><supervisingOfficerName>Sandp11323</supervisingOfficerName><lastKnownResidence><city>WINDSWEPT</city><county>MI</county><state>NV</state><streetAddress1>Address1</streetAddress1><streetName>EASTERN</streetName><streetNumber>6721</streetNumber><zip4>3916</zip4><zip5>89119</zip5></lastKnownResidence><offenseCount>10</offenseCount><actualEndDate>07/09/2014</actualEndDate><county>Conty</county><length>4</length><scheduledEndDate>07/09/2014</scheduledEndDate><dateReported>07/09/2014</dateReported><pubicSaftyId>23</pubicSaftyId><inmateId>32</inmateId><paroleInAbsentiaId>32</paroleInAbsentiaId><race>HISPANIC</race><gender>M</gender><dob>07/09/2014</dob><countyOfBirth>MI</countyOfBirth><stateOfBirth>Michi</stateOfBirth><heightFeet>null</heightFeet><heightInches>null</heightInches><weightInPounds>null</weightInPounds><prisonFacilityType>Sum</prisonFacilityType><prisonFacilityName>FAC</prisonFacilityName><admittedDate>07/09/2014</admittedDate><prisonStatus>Exit</prisonStatus><lastReceiveOrDepartCode>32</lastReceiveOrDepartCode><lastReceiveOrDepartCDate>07/09/2014</lastReceiveOrDepartCDate><recordCreatedTimeStamp>01/02/2 21:11:20</recordCreatedTimeStamp><currentStatusFlag>Y</currentStatusFlag><currentStatusEffectiveDate>07/09/2014</currentStatusEffectiveDate><supervisingOfficerPhone>3234</supervisingOfficerPhone><releaseArrivalDate>07/09/2014</releaseArrivalDate><releaseType>PAROLE</releaseType><releaseCounty>MI</releaseCounty><legalResidenceCounty>MI</legalResidenceCounty><lastParoleReviewDate>08/17/2010</lastParoleReviewDate><is3GOffender>Yes</is3GOffender><isViolentOffender>Yes</isViolentOffender><isSexOffender>Yes</isSexOffender><isOnViolentOffenderProgram>Yes</isOnViolentOffenderProgram><longestTimeToServe>2 Years 1 Months 2 Days</longestTimeToServe><longestTimeToServeDescription>Desc</longestTimeToServeDescription><dischargeDate>07/09/2014</dischargeDate><offenses><sentenceDate>07/09/2014</sentenceDate><length>5</length><offenseCounty>NY</offenseCounty><causeNo>12</causeNo><ncicCode>rr33</ncicCode><offenseCount>6</offenseCount><offenseDate>07/09/2014</offenseDate></offenses><offenses><sentenceDate>07/09/2014</sentenceDate><length>7</length><offenseCounty>MI</offenseCounty><causeNo>45</causeNo><ncicCode>tt44</ncicCode><offenseCount>8</offenseCount><offenseDate>07/09/2014</offenseDate></offenses></criminalParoleRecords><criminalPrisonRecords><custodyType>criminal</custodyType><admittedDate>07/09/2014</admittedDate><location>OGEMAW/WEST BRANCH</location><scheduledReleaseDate>08/17/2010</scheduledReleaseDate><lastGainTime>31/12/2004</lastGainTime><sentence>Sentence Type : PROBATION999266193</sentence><currentStatus>Jail999266193</currentStatus><custodyTypeChangeDate>08/17/2010</custodyTypeChangeDate><gainTimeGranted>5</gainTimeGranted></criminalPrisonRecords><criminalActivitiesRecord><date>31/12/2004</date><description>Desc</description></criminalActivitiesRecord><DOB>31/12/2004</DOB><address><city>WINDSWEPT</city><county>MI</county><state>NV</state><streetAddress1>Address1</streetAddress1><streetName>EASTERN</streetName><streetNumber>6721</streetNumber><zip4>3916</zip4><zip5>89119</zip5></address><stateOfBirth>MI</stateOfBirth><uniqueId>cr01467034129435</uniqueId><race>Y</race><countyOfOrigin>MI</countyOfOrigin><criminalAKAs><first>Jon</first><full>Jon Ki Jr</full><last>Ms.</last><middle>Ki</middle></criminalAKAs><criminalAKAs><first>Keely</first><full>Keely Jon Ms.</full><middle>Jon</middle></criminalAKAs></criminalRecords><uniqueId>cr01467034129435</uniqueId><isIncorrectBPSReport>No</isIncorrectBPSReport><offenseId>-1756511382</offenseId></individualBpsReports><individualBpsReports><offenseType>Criminal Offense</offenseType><ssn>999266193</ssn><firstName>GuestInd</firstName><lastName>Trett</lastName><middleName></middleName><fullName>GuestInd Trett </fullName><state>NV</state><source>Department of Corrections</source><convictiondate></convictiondate><caseType></caseType><criminalRecords><ssn>999266193</ssn><firstName>GuestInd</firstName><lastName>Trett</lastName><fullName>GuestInd Trett </fullName><sex>M</sex><stateOfOrigin>Michigan</stateOfOrigin><caseNumber>06002564-FC-A</caseNumber><caseFilingDate>08/17/2010</caseFilingDate><dataSource>Department of Corrections</dataSource><status>CLIENT DISCHARGED</status><offenderId>1234</offenderId><docNumber>609505</docNumber><caseTypeDescription>criminalreprot</caseTypeDescription><criminalOffenses><caseNumber>06002564-FC-A</caseNumber><caseType>Department Of Correction</caseType><caseTypeDescription>CRIMINAL SEXUAL CONDUCT, 3RD DEGREE</caseTypeDescription><count>45</count><county>MI</county><description>Desc</description><maximumTerm>5Years</maximumTerm><minimumTerm>2Years</minimumTerm><numberCounts>5</numberCounts><offenseDate>08/17/2010</offenseDate><offenseType>OT</offenseType><sentence>Sent Start Date: 20090522</sentence><sentenceLengthDescription>Len Des</sentenceLengthDescription><sentenceDate>07/09/2014</sentenceDate><incarcerationDate>07/09/2014</incarcerationDate><appealDisposition>Crim Appeal</appealDisposition><appealFinalDisposition>Appeal</appealFinalDisposition><arrestCaseNumber>06002564-FC-A</arrestCaseNumber><arrestDate>07/09/2014</arrestDate><arrestDisposition>Department</arrestDisposition><arrestDispositionDate>07/09/2014</arrestDispositionDate><arrestLevel>2</arrestLevel><arrestOffense>Off</arrestOffense><arrestStatute>Arrest</arrestStatute><arrestType>T</arrestType><courtCosts>Cos</courtCosts><courtDescription>CRIMINAL SEXUAL CONDUCT</courtDescription><courtDisposition>Dispo</courtDisposition><courtDispositionDate>07/09/2014</courtDispositionDate><courtFine>Fine</courtFine><courtLevel>2</courtLevel><courtOffense>Off</courtOffense><courtPlea>Plea</courtPlea><courtStatute>Stat</courtStatute><courtSuspendedFine>Sus</courtSuspendedFine><courtSentenceProbation>Y</courtSentenceProbation><courtSentenceSuspended>N</courtSentenceSuspended></criminalOffenses><criminalParoleRecords><startDate>07/09/2014</startDate><currentStatus>DISCHARGE FROM PAROLE 20130607; PAR AMENDED DATE:</currentStatus><name>Dert jill</name><paroleRegion>Houston999266193</paroleRegion><supervisingOffice>MI</supervisingOffice><supervisingOfficerName>Sandp11323</supervisingOfficerName><lastKnownResidence><city>WINDSWEPT</city><county>MI</county><state>NV</state><streetAddress1>Address1</streetAddress1><streetName>EASTERN</streetName><streetNumber>6721</streetNumber><zip4>3916</zip4><zip5>89119</zip5></lastKnownResidence><offenseCount>10</offenseCount><actualEndDate>07/09/2014</actualEndDate><county>Conty</county><length>4</length><scheduledEndDate>07/09/2014</scheduledEndDate><dateReported>07/09/2014</dateReported><pubicSaftyId>23</pubicSaftyId><inmateId>32</inmateId><paroleInAbsentiaId>32</paroleInAbsentiaId><race>HISPANIC</race><gender>M</gender><dob>07/09/2014</dob><countyOfBirth>MI</countyOfBirth><stateOfBirth>Michi</stateOfBirth><heightFeet>null</heightFeet><heightInches>null</heightInches><weightInPounds>null</weightInPounds><prisonFacilityType>Sum</prisonFacilityType><prisonFacilityName>FAC</prisonFacilityName><admittedDate>07/09/2014</admittedDate><prisonStatus>Exit</prisonStatus><lastReceiveOrDepartCode>32</lastReceiveOrDepartCode><lastReceiveOrDepartCDate>07/09/2014</lastReceiveOrDepartCDate><recordCreatedTimeStamp>01/02/2 21:11:20</recordCreatedTimeStamp><currentStatusFlag>Y</currentStatusFlag><currentStatusEffectiveDate>07/09/2014</currentStatusEffectiveDate><supervisingOfficerPhone>3234</supervisingOfficerPhone><releaseArrivalDate>07/09/2014</releaseArrivalDate><releaseType>PAROLE</releaseType><releaseCounty>MI</releaseCounty><legalResidenceCounty>MI</legalResidenceCounty><lastParoleReviewDate>08/17/2010</lastParoleReviewDate><is3GOffender>Yes</is3GOffender><isViolentOffender>Yes</isViolentOffender><isSexOffender>Yes</isSexOffender><isOnViolentOffenderProgram>Yes</isOnViolentOffenderProgram><longestTimeToServe>2 Years 1 Months 2 Days</longestTimeToServe><longestTimeToServeDescription>Desc</longestTimeToServeDescription><dischargeDate>07/09/2014</dischargeDate><offenses><sentenceDate>07/09/2014</sentenceDate><length>5</length><offenseCounty>NY</offenseCounty><causeNo>12</causeNo><ncicCode>rr33</ncicCode><offenseCount>6</offenseCount><offenseDate>07/09/2014</offenseDate></offenses><offenses><sentenceDate>07/09/2014</sentenceDate><length>7</length><offenseCounty>MI</offenseCounty><causeNo>45</causeNo><ncicCode>tt44</ncicCode><offenseCount>8</offenseCount><offenseDate>07/09/2014</offenseDate></offenses></criminalParoleRecords><criminalPrisonRecords><custodyType>criminal</custodyType><admittedDate>07/09/2014</admittedDate><location>OGEMAW/WEST BRANCH</location><scheduledReleaseDate>08/17/2010</scheduledReleaseDate><lastGainTime>31/12/2004</lastGainTime><sentence>Sentence Type : PROBATION999266193</sentence><currentStatus>Jail999266193</currentStatus><custodyTypeChangeDate>08/17/2010</custodyTypeChangeDate><gainTimeGranted>5</gainTimeGranted></criminalPrisonRecords><criminalActivitiesRecord><date>31/12/2004</date><description>Desc</description></criminalActivitiesRecord><DOB>31/12/2004</DOB><address><city>WINDSWEPT</city><county>MI</county><state>NV</state><streetAddress1>Address1</streetAddress1><streetName>EASTERN</streetName><streetNumber>6721</streetNumber><zip4>3916</zip4><zip5>89119</zip5></address><stateOfBirth>MI</stateOfBirth><uniqueId>cr01467034129435</uniqueId><race>Y</race><countyOfOrigin>MI</countyOfOrigin><criminalAKAs><first>Jon</first><full>Jon Ki Jr</full><last>Ms.</last><middle>Ki</middle></criminalAKAs><criminalAKAs><first>Keely</first><full>Keely Jon Ms.</full><middle>Jon</middle></criminalAKAs></criminalRecords><uniqueId>cr01467034129435</uniqueId><isIncorrectBPSReport>No</isIncorrectBPSReport><offenseId>-416435373</offenseId></individualBpsReports><individualBpsReports><offenseType>Sexual Offense</offenseType><ssn>999266193</ssn><firstName>GuestInd</firstName><lastName>Trett</lastName><middleName></middleName><fullName>GuestInd Trett </fullName><state>MI</state><source>Court</source><convictiondate>07/07/2014</convictiondate><caseType>Desc</caseType><sexualOffense><primaryKey>3</primaryKey><recordType>RDC</recordType><name>GuestInd Trett </name><address><city>WINDSWEPT</city><county>MI</county><state>NV</state><streetAddress1>Address1</streetAddress1><streetName>EASTERN</streetName><streetNumber>6721</streetNumber><zip4>3916</zip4><zip5>89119</zip5></address><SSN>999266193</SSN><origSSN>999266193</origSSN><uniqueId>1467034129435</uniqueId><DOB>07/09/2014</DOB><DOB2>07/09/2014</DOB2><dateFirstSeen>07/09/2014</dateFirstSeen><dateLastSeen>07/09/2014</dateLastSeen><stateOfOrigin>Mich</stateOfOrigin><originStateCode>MI</originStateCode><offenderStatus>G</offenderStatus><offenderCategory>Cat</offenderCategory><riskLevelCode>c</riskLevelCode><riskDescription>RD</riskDescription><policeAgency><name>Mercy</name><contactName>JOHN</contactName><phone>xxxxxx</phone><address><city>WINDSWEPT</city><county>MI</county><state>NV</state><streetAddress1>Address1</streetAddress1><streetName>EASTERN</streetName><streetNumber>6721</streetNumber><zip4>3916</zip4><zip5>89119</zip5></address></policeAgency><school><name>XXXXx</name><address1>MI</address1><address2>MI</address2><address3>MI</address3><address4>KINGSLEY</address4><address5>KINGSLEY5</address5><county>MI</county></school><employer><name>XXXXx</name><address1>MI</address1><address2>KINGSLEY</address2><address3>Houston</address3><address4>MI</address4><address5>MI5</address5><county>M</county></employer><registration><date1>07/09/2014</date1><date1Type>T1</date1Type><date2>07/09/2014</date2><date2Type>T2</date2Type><date3>05/09/2014</date3><date3Type>T3</date3Type><address1>KINGSLEY</address1><address2>MI</address2><address3>Houston</address3><address4>chicg</address4><address5>chicg5</address5><county>C</county><type>T</type></registration><physicalCharacteristics><sex>M</sex></physicalCharacteristics><idNumbers><offenderId>MISOR256576</offenderId><docNumber>06002564XX</docNumber><sorNumber>SOR9876</sorNumber><stateIdNumber>876</stateIdNumber><fbiNumber>06002564FBI</fbiNumber><ncicNumber>234234</ncicNumber></idNumbers><additionalComment1>AC1</additionalComment1><additionalComment2>AC2</additionalComment2><scConvictions><convictionJurisdiction>Juri</convictionJurisdiction><convictionDate>07/07/2014</convictionDate><courtName>Court</courtName><courtCaseNumber>46765454</courtCaseNumber><offenseDate>05/09/2014</offenseDate><offenseCodeOrStatute>Test</offenseCodeOrStatute><offenseDescription>Desc</offenseDescription><victimAge>23</victimAge><victimGender>M</victimGender><victimRelationship>Cousin</victimRelationship><sentenceDescription>SsDesc</sentenceDescription></scConvictions><sexualOffAKAs><first>Jon</first><full>Jon Ki Jr</full><last>Jr</last><middle>Ki</middle></sexualOffAKAs><sexualOffAKAs><first>Keely</first><full>Keely Jon Ms.</full><last>Ms.</last><middle>Jon</middle></sexualOffAKAs></sexualOffense><uniqueId>1467034129435</uniqueId><isIncorrectBPSReport>No</isIncorrectBPSReport><offenseId>-638306316</offenseId></individualBpsReports><displayID>0</displayID></ownershipResponseDetails><ownershipResponseDetails><referenceID>22302</referenceID><hasSanctions>Yes</hasSanctions><hasLEIESanctions>Yes</hasLEIESanctions><hasEPLSSanctions>Yes</hasEPLSSanctions><isdeceasedFlag>Yes</isdeceasedFlag><sanctions><address>    </address><boardType>FEDERAL BOARDS</boardType><fraudAbuseFlag></fraudAbuseFlag><lostOfLicenseIndicator></lostOfLicenseIndicator><name>aa dd</name><sanctionDate>03/03/2015</sanctionDate><sanctionId>1353</sanctionId><sanctionReason>MET ALL REQUIREMENTS FOR REINSTATEMENT</sanctionReason><sanctionState>MI</sanctionState><sanctionTerm></sanctionTerm><sanctionType>OTHER</sanctionType><source>SAM</source><sourceType>Federal</sourceType><isIncorrectSanction>No</isIncorrectSanction><sanctionName>aa dd</sanctionName><screeningSource></screeningSource></sanctions><leastSanctionRecord><address>    </address><boardType>FEDERAL BOARDS</boardType><fraudAbuseFlag></fraudAbuseFlag><lostOfLicenseIndicator></lostOfLicenseIndicator><name>aa dd</name><sanctionDate>03/03/2015</sanctionDate><sanctionId>1353</sanctionId><sanctionReason>MET ALL REQUIREMENTS FOR REINSTATEMENT</sanctionReason><sanctionState>MI</sanctionState><sanctionTerm></sanctionTerm><sanctionType>OTHER</sanctionType><source>SAM</source><sourceType>Federal</sourceType><isIncorrectSanction>No</isIncorrectSanction><sanctionName>aa dd</sanctionName><screeningSource></screeningSource></leastSanctionRecord><ssnVerified>Yes</ssnVerified><ssn>555555555</ssn><name>aa , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  dd </name><isPossibleRelative></isPossibleRelative><hasCriminalHistory>Yes</hasCriminalHistory><individualBpsReports><offenseType>Criminal Offense</offenseType><ssn>555555555</ssn><firstName>aa</firstName><lastName>dd</lastName><middleName></middleName><fullName>aa , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  dd </fullName><state>NV</state>';
begin
update ANS_CODEDIT_1 set 
KNK_RESP= UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(v_cl)
where KNK_REQ_SID='22302';
dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literal it's to long. BLOB can hold up to 4GB, BUT:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/pcmus.htm
```

"PLS-00172: string literal too long
Cause: The string literal was longer than 32767 bytes.
Action: Use a string literal of at most 32767 bytes."

Your v_cl is just too long.

One way is to cut this XML into smaller parts and by PL/SQL make few updates.

Comment: Is there any way to update the same size text into the column? Or any alternate ways without making changes in the table?

Comment: Alternate way - store this xml string in XMLType then convert it to clob/blob. Try this article. Or if this code won't suits you, there's plenty of similar solutions.
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_to_xml_type.htm

Comment: Thank you very much